# Javascript Multiplication table

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am attempting to create a table displaying an `n` by `n` table, with the following details:

- Size (`n`) determined by the user's input
- I would like to color code the even rows a certain color and the odd another color
- The results will pop up in a new window/tab

This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <form name="f"> 
        <input type="text" value ="r" size="6" name="r">
        <input type="text" value ="c" size="6" name="c">
        <input type="button" value="make table" onclick="happy(r.value,c.value)">
    </form>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function happy(rows, cols) {
    var hcode = '';

    w=window.open();
    w.document.write("<table border='1'>");
    for (i=0; i<=rows; i++) {
        w.document.write("<td>"+i)
    }

    for (j=1; j<=cols; j++) {
        var x = 0;
        w.document.write("<tr><td>"+j);
        //w.document.write("<td>"+j*x);
    }

    w.document.write("<tr>")
    for ( x=1; x<= rows; x++) {
        w.document.write("<tr>");

        for ( n=1; n<= cols; n++) {
            if (x %2==0 ) {
                w.document.write("<td bgcolor='aquamarine'>"+x*n+"</td>");
                if ( n<=cols) {
                    w.document.write()
                }
            }
            else {
                w.document.write("<td bgcolor='coral'>"+x*n+"</td>");
            }
        }
    }
    w.document.write('</table')
```

I've played around with a few variations but none resulting in what I need.  Any and all advice welcomed! Thanks!

Comment: document.write will close tags...You are not building a string.

Comment: So what does your code actually do? What error messages are you seeing (if any)? What *exactly* are you having trouble with.

Comment: Don't even use `document.write()`.

Comment: Also note, your table is *r* x *c* not *n* x *n*

Comment: I can get the table to successfully make an n by n, but to fill in the rest of the table by multiplying the rows by columns is what I can't figure out

Comment: Yes you are correct that's what I mean.

Comment: Just use w.("<td>")  etc?

Comment: @swam: Don't use `document.write` at all. Use DOM manipulation like `document.createElement("table")` and then use `appendChild` to add nodes to the table.

Comment: @epascarello: *"document.write will close tags...You are not building a string."* In effect, you are; or rather, it comes to the same thing: You're outputting a stream of text that will be interpreted by an HTML parser. You have to output close tags according to the same rules you have to write them in an HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand the need.

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/kb294v6a/

Is it what you want ?

JS (with jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    makeTable();
    $('form').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        makeTable();
    });
});

function makeTable(){
    var rows = parseInt($('input[name=r]').val()),
        col = parseInt($('input[name=c]').val());

    if(typeof rows === 'number' && rows > 0 && typeof col === 'number' && col > 0){
        var table = '<table>';
        for(var i = 1; i <= rows; i++){
            table += '<tr>';
            for(var j = 1; j <= col; j++){
                table += '<td>'+i*j+'</td>';
            }
            table += '</tr>';
        }
        table += '</table>';
        $('#table').html(table);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a basic multiplication table where you can style each row, this should do the job:

```
function multiplicationTable(x, y){
  var Y = typeof y === 'number' ? y : x;
  var table = '<table><tbody>';
  for(var i=0,l=Y+1; i<l, i++){
    table += i%2 === 0 ? "<tr class='odd'>" : "<tr class='even'>";
    table += '<th>'+i+'</th>';
    for(var n=1,c=x+1; n<c; n++){
      if(i === 0){
       table += '<th>'+n+'</th>';
      }
      else{
        table += '<td>'+i*n+'</td>';
      }
    }
    table += '</tr>';
  }
  return table + '</tbody></table>';
}
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = multiplicationTable(12);
console.log(multiplicationTable(15, 25));
```